# How to ignore session warning when include a file in php

Tags: php, wordpress

when I am using include() with my wordpress plugin which says an error as follows.

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /var/www/wordpress3/wp-content/plugins/new/listAllItems.php:10) in /var/www/wordpress3/wp-content/themes/thesis_16/lib/functions/document.php on line 3
```

listallitems.php's 10 th line says

`

```
    include_once("../../../wp-config.php");
    include_once("../../../wp-load.php");
     ....`
```

How can I avoid this error.

Comment: Please do a little bit of research first, especially since this is about the most common problem encountered with PHP and [has been answered a gazillion times already](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+headers+already+sent).

Comment: Usually this error appears when there is output before session start function. sometimes even blank space or small character, file encoding problems.

Answer (score 1):

As explained before, this is due to some text which was already sent to the browser before your session_start() statement. Check if you haven't includes spaces/characters in your script or in one of the scripts your are including.

THis could also be an encoding problem, i.e. your file is encoded in UTF-8 with BOM but your webserver is configured in another charset, so the BOM is treated as extra characters (but this problem has indeed be answered a lot of times).

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quick-fix, not the right solution.

Put an "@" symbol before the command, like this...

@session_start();

That will suppress any warnings or errors. You can do that with any PHP command. But it's not a good idea in general, because you are only putting a band-aid on the issue, and not resolving the root cause, which in your case is that the session_start() is getting called after something has been output to the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I have just added in my script :

```
if(!session_start()){
  session_start();
}
```

All warnings gone.